# Как отдельно написать этот кусок функцией?

Tags: c++, рефакторинг, функции

```
void main()
{
    int n,q,m,w;
    bool pr;
    cin>>n>>m;
    Queue Q1=CreateQueue(n),Q2=CreateQueue(m);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {cin>>q; Enq(Q1,(void*)q);}
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {cin>>q; Enq(Q2,(void*)q);}

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pr=false;
        q=(int)Deq(Q1);
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            w=(int)Deq(Q2);
            if (q==w) pr=true;
            Enq(Q2,(void*)w);
        }
        if (!pr) cout<<q<<endl;
        Enq(Q1,(void*)q);
    }   
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        pr=false;
        q=(int)Deq(Q2);
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            w=(int)Deq(Q1);
            if (q==w) pr=true;
            Enq(Q1,(void*)w);
        }
        if (!pr) cout<<q<<endl;
        Enq(Q2,(void*)q);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

А в чем проблема вынести? смотрим на нее - она не должна ничего возвращать, а вот `Q1` `Q2` должны передаваться как параметры. Итого.

```
void my_func(Queue Q1, Queue Q2)
{
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pr=false;
        q=(int)Deq(Q1);
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            w=(int)Deq(Q2);
            if (q==w) pr=true;
            Enq(Q2,(void*)w);
        }
        if (!pr) cout<<q<<endl;
        Enq(Q1,(void*)q);
    }   
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        pr=false;
        q=(int)Deq(Q2);
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            w=(int)Deq(Q1);
            if (q==w) pr=true;
            Enq(Q1,(void*)w);
        }
        if (!pr) cout<<q<<endl;
        Enq(Q2,(void*)q);
    }   
}

void main()
{
    int n,q,m,w;
    bool pr;
    cin>>n>>m;
    Queue Q1=CreateQueue(n),Q2=CreateQueue(m);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {cin>>q; Enq(Q1,(void*)q);}
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {cin>>q; Enq(Q2,(void*)q);}

    my_func(Q1, Q2);
}
```

и это все. Конечно, в реальном коде я бы чуточку по другому написал сигнатуру, например так

```
void my_func(Queue &Q1, Queue &Q2)
```

или так

```
void my_func(const Queue &Q1, const Queue &Q2)
```

эти сигнатуры будут работать и для Вашего кода.

Comment: Я еще добавлю, что надо передавать длины и код циклов можно сократить в два раза, поскольку Q1 и Q2 просто меняются местами.

> void my_func(Queue &Q1, Queue &Q2,int n,int m){

> int q,w;

> bool pr;

> for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
>     {
>         pr=false;
>         q=(int)Deq(Q1);
>         for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
>         {

>             w=(int)Deq(Q2);

>             if (q==w) pr=true;

>             Enq(Q2,(void*)w);

>         }

>         if (!pr) cout<<q<<endl;

>         Enq(Q1,(void*)q);

>     }   

> }

> void main(){

> ...

> my_func(&Q1,&Q2,n,m);

> my_func(&Q2,&Q1,m,n);

}